# How can I enable user switching in Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, switch-user

I've just installed Xubuntu 14.04 in my desktop PC but I just cannot get user switching working. It's funny because in the session menu on top right it does appear but in gray and unclickable just like the hibernate function does.

If anyone could help me out, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks!!

Comment: Look at this http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2218401

Answer (score 2):

From [TuKsn's link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2218401), right click on the Whisker icon (top right) and you get a 'Properties' menu entry, from there, switch to the 'Behavior' tab and enable the 'Switch Users' option.

Comment: In Xubuntu 15.10, the "Switch Users" option is under the "Commands" tab instead of "Behavior".